# Show if $X,Y$ are independent RV's (discrete or continuous) then $k+X,Y$ and $kX,Y$ are indepedent for $k \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Show if $X,Y$ are independent RV's (discrete or continuous) then $k+X,Y$ and $kX,Y$ are indepedent for $k \in \mathbb R$.

I've been thinking how to prove the above statement. Intuitivelly it's correct, but how to prove it in numbers using theory ?

Comment: The sigma-algebras generated by $k+X$ and $kX$ are the same as the sigma-algebra generated by $X$ (for $k\neq 0$ at least).

Comment: Do you plan to delete the present post after it gets some answers, as you deleted [this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768620/6179) with neither warning nor explanation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(X,Y)$ are independant iff for every positive valued functions $f,g$ 
$$
E(f(X)g(Y))=Ef(X) Eg(Y)
$$

details:

let $f,g$ positive valued functions and let
$f_1(x) = f(x+k);
\\
f_2(x) = f(kx).$

Then
$$
E(f(X+k)g(Y)) = E(f_1(X)g(Y))= Ef_1(X) Eg(Y) = Ef(X+k) Eg(Y)\\
E(f(kX)g(Y)) = E(f_2(X)g(Y)) = Ef_2(X) Eg(Y) =  Ef(kX) Eg(Y).
$$

Comment: Is this the easiest way of showing this ?

Comment: Thank you @mookid, but I thought there was some obvious way of proving this without using the expectation etc.

Comment: But this IS an obvious proof....

Comment: Define "easiest".